# How do I map thorough the entire array which contains other objects and arrays as well in React?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, json

I have created a JavaScript array that contains some other objects. the subobjects contain arrays. Now I want to iterate through the entire parent object in React. I use the following approach but it does not work:

**Array**

```
const users =[
    {
        id:1,
        username: "user1",
        path: "/user",
        listItems: {lists:["list-1", "List-2", "List-3", "List-4", "List-5"], path: ["/list-1", "/List-2", "/List-3", "/List-4", "/List-5"]}
    },
    {
        id:2,
        username: "user2",
        path: "/user2",
        listItems: {lists:["list-1", "List-2", "List-3", "List-4", "List-5"], path: ["/list-1", "/List-2", "/List-3", "/List-4", "/List-5"]}
    },
    {
        id:3,
        username: "user3",
        path: "/user3",
        listItems: {lists:["list-1", "List-2", "List-3", "List-4", "List-5"], path: ["/list-1", "/List-2", "/List-3", "/List-4", "/List-5"]}
    }
]
```

**usersInfo component**

```
export default function usersInfo(props){
const users = props.users;
return(
<div className="container">
{users.map((item)=>{
    return(
        <section className="user">
        <h1>{item.username}</h1>
        <p>{item.path}</p>
        <Link href={item.path}>Visit</Link>
        <p>Users lists</p>
        <ul>
        {item.listItems.map((topic)=>{
            <Link href={topic.path}<li>{topic.lists}</li>
        })}
        </ul>
        </section>  
)})}

</div>
)}
```

Using `usersInfo` coponent in React:

```
<usersInfo users = {users}/>
```

Everything works fine. But I get an issue when trying to map through the `listItems` object which contains two arrays `lists` and `path`.
How do I solve this?

I expect the output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missing that,

replace this, this is wrong .map() wont work here, as `listItems` its json object, you need change this code,

```
    <ul>
    {item.listItems.map((topic)=>{
        <Link href={topic.path}<li>{topic.lists}</li>
    })}
    </ul>
```

replace to this, this will work

```
<ul>
{
  item.listItems.lists.map((list)=>{
    <li>{list}</li>
  })
  item.listItems.path.map((topic)=>{
    <Link href={topic.path}<li>{topic.lists}</li>
  })
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the data you have correctly. For example, to access the `lists` related to a user, it should be `item.listItems.lists`. This should work:

```
export default function usersInfo({ users }) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {users.map((item) => {
        return (
          <section className="user" key={item.id}>
            <h1>{item.username}</h1>
            <p>{item.path}</p>
            <Link href={item.path}>Visit</Link>
            <p>Users lists</p>
            <ul>
              {item.listItems.lists.map((l, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                  <Link href={item.listItems.path[index]}>{l}</Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </section>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You were also missing some `key` prop.

Answer (score 0):

If it's guaranteed that `lists` and `paths` indices match and you want your `<li>` elements to contain the links, you can simply do:

```
<ul>
    {item.listItems.lists.map((listItem, listIndex)=>{
       return(<li><Link href={item.listItems.path[listIndex]}>{listItem}</Link></li>);
    })}
</ul>
```

Comment: I am having an error with your code. The error is this:  **Type Error: ** `item.listItems.map is not a function`

Comment: Now there is no error. But the `lists`  are not rendering in the browser.

Comment: Please let me tell you that this code works fine 
`{item.listItems.map((topic) => (<li>{topic}</li>))}` 
              
if I have only one array inside an object. Like `listItems: ["list-1", "List-2", "List-3", "List-4", "List-5"]` .But when I make `listItems` an object like which contains two arrays `lists` and `path` like this `listItems: {lists:["list-1", "List-2", "List-3", "List-4", "List-5"], path: ["/list-1", "/List-2", "/List-3", "/List-4", "/List-5"]}` 

then I get an error!

Comment: What actually is the expected behaviour? Do you want to display each `list`-item separately with the corresponding `path` item?

Comment: No! I want them to match. Can this be resolved?

Comment: I have edited the question and attached an expected HTML output as an image.

Comment: I see, a `return(...)` was missing, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use map method on an Object. map is a Array method and not available for object. `Object.keys.map` must solve this.

```
export default function usersInfo(props){
const users = props.users;
return(
<div className="container">
{users.map((item)=>{
    return(
        <section className="user">
        <h1>{item.username}</h1>
        <p>{item.path}</p>
        <Link href={item.path}>Visit</Link>
        <p>Users lists</p>
        <ul>
        {Object.keys(item.listItems)[0].map((list, i)=>{
          
            <Link href={item.listItems.path[i]}<li>{list}</li>
        })}
        </ul>
        </section>  
)})}

</div>
)}
```

Comment: No error. But nothing happened! `lists` did not get rendered in the browser.